# Need help in understanding the value returned by JButton's getInsets() method

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a difficult time in understanding the return value of JButton's getInsets() method. On reading the documentation, I got that the getInsets() method returns the insets of the button's border (if a border is set on the button), which specifies the amount of space the border needs to draw itself.

However, on executing the following code:

```
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonMarginInsets {   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test Frame");        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Test Button");       
        System.out.println("Button Border Insets " + button.getBorder().getBorderInsets(button));        
        button.setMargin(new Insets(100, 10, 10, 10));       
        System.out.println("Button Insets " + button.getInsets());       

        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

I'm getting the following console output:

> Button Border Insets java.awt.Insets[top=5,left=17,bottom=5,right=17]
>
> Button Insets java.awt.Insets[top=103,left=13,bottom=13,right=13]

and the following frame:
[Frame Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s018j.png)

My questions are:

1. How the top, left, bottom, right values specify the amount of space
   the border needs to draw itself?
2. Why these insets change on setting the margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, first things first. Both your calls to `button.getInsets()` and `getBorderInsets(button)` are *identical*, as you have seen in the documentation, and confirmed by the [source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JComponent.java#L1838) (internally, `getInsets()` just calls `getBorderInsets(this)` anyway).

Now that that's out of the way, by default a `JButton` is decorated with a [CompoundBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html). If you look at [the source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicBorders.java#L55), you can see that the CompoundBorder used for buttons consists of:

- An *outside border* of type `BasicBorders.ButtonBorder`, and
- An *inside border* of type `MarginBorder`.

The `MarginBorder` is probably your point of interest here. It has an override for `getBorderInsets()` [that returns the component's margins](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicBorders.java#L475).

So, in conclusion, a JButton's border is actually composite of TWO borders. The actual bounding lines outside (that you traditionally would think as a 'border', making it look 3d), plus a margin border inside. So when you do a `setMargin()`, you are also affecting the *inside* part of your compound border.

This explains your result of:

> Button Insets java.awt.Insets[top=**103**,left=**13**,bottom=**13**,right=**13**]

The outside lines are **3**px wide each, and your margin is (**100,10,10,10**) giving you the above total border inset.

Comment: That explains it! Thank you @NPras!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do this using the components insets. So call something like:

```
Insets insets = component.getInsets();
insets.set(top, left, bottom, right);
```

You should do this after setting the border on the component.

> An Insets is a simple class that contains 4 fields: top, left, bottom
>   and right. Insets are used to describe the padding surrounding a
>   component. Every Border in Swing is expected to return an Insets
>   object describing how much padding to add to the component for the
>   Border to render correctly.

[Custom Swing Component Development Tip: Insets Matter](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-swing-component)